# Starting to learn linux

Tags: 20.04, software-installation, authentication

I have windows PC with a VM installed.  I installed Ubuntu 20.04 to learn Linux.
I am unable to install anything due to an Authentication required.
I have seen there is a way to disable this authenication requirement.
Is there a script or a list of the commands to disable it?

Comment: Please tell us an example of what you want to install and how you try to do it.

Comment: Why do you want to disable it? Just type your password (the same that you use to login to the machine) in the "authentication required" window.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include which VM engine you installed Ubuntu with? A VirtualBox or VMware installation will act differently from a WSL2 installation …

Answer (score 3):

When you installed Ubuntu you choosed a user name and a password. When asked for authentication simply enter the password choosen earlier.

Comment: My apologies! I obviously forgot I had selected a Password on installation. I removed Ubuntu and Installed it again. I will remember the password!  Will also pay more attention! Thank You!!